# WooCommerce: Hide css propriety when an element is empty

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to add a custom field into the products list in the shop page of my website.
I used this code in `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'ins_woocommerce_product_excerpt', 3);  

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if (!function_exists('ins_woocommerce_product_excerpt'))
{
    function ins_woocommerce_product_excerpt() {

        global $post;
        $item = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'item12', true );

        if ( $item !== "" || is_home() || is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) {


            echo '<span class="item12"><em>';
            echo ( $item );
            echo '</em></span>';

        }
    }
}
```

The code works and shows the custom field (with a green label made in css),
over the image product in the shop page.

css codes:

```css
.item12 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -3.750em;
    z-index: 8;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: black 0.063em 0.063em 0.313em;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    background-color: rgba(89, 140, 31, 0.71);
    border-radius: 0.438em;
    padding: 0.313em 0.313em 0.313em 0.313em;
    position: absolute;
    /* margin-top: -100px; */
    margin-left: 9.375em;
}
```

The problem is when the custom field is empty, a green dot is visibile over the image.

How can I do to show the label only when the custom field is not empty?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Add New Code in function.php Like This**:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'ins_woocommerce_product_excerpt', 3);  

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if (!function_exists('ins_woocommerce_product_excerpt'))
{
    function ins_woocommerce_product_excerpt() {

        global $post;
        $item = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'item12', true );

        if ( $item !== "" || is_home() || is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) {

            if(!empty($item)){
                echo '<span class="item12"><em>';
                echo ( $item );
                echo '</em></span>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```